# remove characters from pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to simply remove the '(' and ')' from the beginning and end of the pandas column series. This is my best guess so far but it just returns empty strings with () intact.

```
postings['location'].replace('[^\(.*\)?]','', regex=True)
```

The column looks like this:
[screenshot of jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwo7q.png)

Comment: You don't need regex if you just want to remove characters from the beginning or end of the string. `strip` should be enough. `postings['location'].str.strip("()")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Working example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(location=['(hello)']))

print(df)

  location
0  (hello)
```

***@Psidom's Solution***
*`str.strip`*

```
df.location.str.strip('()')

0    hello
Name: location, dtype: object
```

***Option 2***
*`str.extract`*

```
df.location.str.extract('\((.*)\)', expand=False)

0    hello
Name: location, dtype: object
```

***Option 3***
*`str.replace`*

```
df.location.str.replace('\(|\)', '')

0    hello
Name: location, dtype: object
```

***Option 4***
*`replace`*

```
df.location.replace('\(|\)', '', regex=True)

0    hello
Name: location, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks!  Option 4 worked.  Most of the other options only remove the closing bracket and not the opening one in my jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with `[^\(.*\)?]` is **match all other characters than you mentioned in character class**. `^` inside character class means negating that set.

Should try with `^\(|\)$` and replace with `""` i.e empty string.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7P5p89/1)**