# Pandas removing characters from String

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to simplify my 3 line code to rid of the square brackets into one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(words=['[hello]',
                            '[hello,[Name, World, Max]',
                            np.nan, 
                            '[Goodbye]',
                            np.nan,
                            '[hello, [goodbye], hello]']))
df['words'].fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
df['words']=df['words'].str.extract("\[", "")
df['words']=df['words'].str.replace("\]", "")
```

I tried several methods mentioned here but did not work (replace, expand): [remove characters from pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768023/remove-characters-from-pandas-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with values in `[]`:

```
df['words'] = df['words'].fillna("N/A").str.replace("[\]\[]", "")
```

Or use `|` for regex `or`:

```
df['words'] = df['words'].fillna("N/A").str.replace("\]|\[", "")
```

---

```
print (df)
                    words
0                   hello
1  hello,Name, World, Max
2                     N/A
3                 Goodbye
4                     N/A
5   hello, goodbye, hello
```

Comment: @user2266957 - One idea - `df['words'] = df['words'].fillna("N/A").astype(str).str.replace("[\]\[]", "")`

Comment: This works! Can you explain why the addition of [ ] is needed?

Comment: @ohoh7171 - Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789445/2901002)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(words=['[hello]',
                            '[hello,[Name, World, Max]',
                            np.nan, 
                            '[Goodbye]',
                            np.nan,
                            '[hello, [goodbye], hello]']))
df ['words'] = df['words'].fillna("N/A", inplace=False).replace('\[{0,1}\]{0,1}', '', regex=True)
```